# Como formatar os números diretamente pelo SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Senhores, meus números estão saindo sem formatação quando realizo o select diretamente no banco, estão saindo da seguinte forma:

```
REALIZADO             META
61274436,2090003    80000000,00
```

Como posso fazer com que eles saiam legíveis para quem for interpreta-los?

Comment: Defina legíveis para quem for interpretá-los

Comment: imagino que seja `sql-server` por conta da função `datepart` correto? O que seria legíveis pra vc? Arredondar?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo nesse caso, gostaria de inserir as pontuações em suas posições corretas.

Comment: É o Sql-server mesmo @RicardoPontual, não quero arredonda-los, apenas inserir as pontuações em seus devidos lugares.

Comment: Isso deveria ser feito em sua aplicação através de máscaras, caso contrário você não terá mais valores númericos, apenas textos. Onde você exibe essas informações e o que mais faz com elas após a consulta?

Comment: Assim: "61.274.436,2090003"? Mas o usuário/você vão ler o resultado direto do `sql` ou em uma aplicação (formulário, página web, etc)? Porque a responsabilidade da formatação é da apresentação, mas se não tiver isso, só o resultado do banco é possível de formatar

Comment: Se você usa `SQL Server 2012` ou mais atual, tem a função **format**: `select FORMAT(61274436.2090003,'#,0.0000', 'pt-BR')`, veja se é isso que precisa que eu coloca numa resposta detalhando melhor

Comment: É isso mesmo que preciso @RicardoPontual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a partir do **SQL SERVER 2012**, você pode usar a função [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx)  :

```
SELECT FORMAT(A.REALIZADO,'#,0.0000', 'pt-BR') ...
```

Usando só o padrão '#0.0000' irá formatar a exibição usando pontuação, mas será exibido de acordo com a configuração *SQL Server*, que se estiver configurado em inglês por exemplo, vai exibir "61,274,436.2090". Para exibir no format correto, usar o último parâmetro, que é a "cultura", no exemplo, usei "pt-BR" para exibir pontos nos milhares e vírgula nos decimais.

Pode ser usado com tipos tanto numéricos como data, verificar a tabela no link acima com a documentação.

Comment: Ricardo, essa query será inserida em meu JavaScript, tentei inserir mas ele não reconheceu, eu já estava utilizando a query, mas só implementar essa nova funcionalidade que o meu JavaScript não reconheceu, sabe se tem alguma outra maneira para poder utiliza-lo dentro do meu código?

Comment: No `javascript`? Geralmente colocamos isso no código lado servidor (`c#`, `php`, `Java`, etc), ou você está usando `node-js`?

Comment: Essa é a query que já utilizo hoje dentro da minha JSP e funciona. <snk:query var="SG">
    SELECT
    A.REALIZADO,
    A.META,
    FLOOR((A.REALIZADO/A.META)*100) AS ACUMULADO

    FROM (

    SELECT 
    ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM((ITE1.QTDNEG*ITE1.VLRUNIT)-ITE1.VLRDESC-ITE1.VLRREPRED),0)....     Após implementar essa configuração que vc me informou ela não reconhece mais, só funciona no banco...

Comment: estranho porque deveria apenas passar a query para o banco, e se funciona no banco deve funcionar também no código. Só repare que, se antes o resultado era um valor numérico, do tipo `decimal` ou `float`, não sei bem o tipo da campo da sua tabela, usando `format` ele será agora `nvarchar`, verifique se o seu código está tratando os campos que estão usando `format` como `nvarchar`, senão vai dar erro no retorno da query